# Xpath Element or Element within a path

Tags: xslt, xpath, dita

in the following xpath:

`/bookmap/concept/task/title`

what I really want to do is replace "task" with "task or concept".

It turns out, inserting the `|` operator in this context turns it into a union I think and the results are not what I was hoping for in the DITA Open Toolkit context where I was trying to do this.  `|` works as or if you are testing the content of a tag as in:  `/some-tag[pattern1 or pattern2]`

is there a way in xpath to simply do this:

`/bookmap/concept/task or concept/title`

Looking for the right syntax if it exists.  Otherwise, I'll just do separate match rules for the different contexts, but an "or scenario" would be cleaner if it were possible.

This cheat sheet put me onto my mistake when it first failed:
https://devhints.io/xpath

Comment: Which result do you want? In XPath 2 and later you can certainly use `/bookmap/concept/(task | concept)/title` but it will select both `task` and `concept` children if they exist. In XPath 1 (and later, of course) there is `/bookmap/concept/*[self::task or self::concept]/title`, again, if the `concept` child has both `task` and `concept` children, all will be selected.

Comment: I think your answer would meet the need (if it works - I will test it).  I was looking to merge these paths into one statement:  `/bookmap/concept/task ...`, or `/bookmap/task/task ...` so that the single rule would apply to both tagging contexts.  If all I was missing was the parenthesies to get it to understand what I meant, that would be great!

Comment: well this is strange:  on the xsltfiddle site - I test `/(section|doc)/ ... rest of my xpath` and it works.  In my code (which is used in a DITA OT xsl file), I use a similar path  like this: `/bookmap/(concept|task)/task/title` and it fails to compile.  I can fix all by just doing 2 rules (one w/ concept and one w/ task) but if it works in regular xsl, I don't get why it won't work in the Open toolkit.  This one may defy explanation.  Given that the syntax works on the xslfiddle site, if @MartinHonnen wants to post his answer, I'll accept it and chalk this up to oddities in the OT (2.5.2).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be

```
    /bookmap//title
```

This allows any path between bookmap and title.
If you want to limit the possible paths as per the original post, you can try this:

```
/bookmap/concept/*[name()='task' or name()='concept']/title
```

Comment: hope to test this at work soon.  We are using DITA OT 2.5.2 where standard xsl syntax of somepath/(element or element)/more-of-path ... does not work.  This looks promising based on what I have seen that does work so far.